# My headphones appear in the output section in my Mac but there's no sound coming out of them

Tags: mac, audio, headphones, sound-volume, speakers

I tried of course to connect them to another device and they work.
I cleaned the hole with a small air pump I use to clean the in-space between buttons.
The sound works fine when I unplug them, but stops when I put the headphones in.
In **System Preferences**  > **Sound** > **Output**, they appear as usual, and everything seems alright.

I haven't dropped the Mac or anything. It's always on the table in the house. Nobody touches it but me. I didn't give any signs of failure. What should I do?

edit:
They used to work but now they stopped. They have a cable. It's a MacBook Air 2020 Big Sur.

Comment: Do you connect your headphones to your Mac with a cable? (It sounds so but I just wanted to verify.) If so, what happens when you try another pair of headphones with cable with your Mac? What is your Mac's model (iMac, MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, etc.) & year and which macOS (Catalina, Monterey, etc. and version) is installed on it? (You can figure these out by clicking on the Apple logo at the top left of your Mac's screen and then clicking on "About This Mac".)

Comment: Did they used to work, but stopped, or have you never tried them before with this Mac?

Comment: They used to work but now they stopped. They have a cable. It's a MacBook Air 2020 Big Sur.